# VueJs cant access items outside of my created hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to access some JSON data that I load during creation, it loads in my created hook but when I try to access it outside of the created hook, it doesn't return anything. The console log that does the 'axios load' shows my JSON, the inside mounted does not. Any ideas?

Here is my code.

```
data(){
            return{
                dataset: "",
                baseUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
            }

        },
created() {
            console.log('Mounted: base URL',this.baseUrl);
            axios.get(this.baseUrl + '/mockdata/piemock.json').then(response => {
                this.dataset =response.data;
                console.log('axios load', this.dataset);
            })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log('axios error', e)
                });
        },
        mounted() {
            // define data
            console.log("this.dataset", this.dataset);
            console.log("this.baseurl", this.baseUrl);
}
```

**UPDATE**
To follow on with what AlexMA said in his post, here is the new code. the console log that says axios called never gets called?

```
data(){
            this.fakeAxiosCall()
                .then((theData) => (
                    console.log('axios called', theData),
                    this.dataset = theData
                ))
                .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
            return{
                dataset: "",
                baseUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
            }

        },

methods: {
            fakeAxiosCall:  function() {
                return axios.get(this.baseUrl + '/mockdata/piemock.json')
            }
        },
```

**UPDATE 2 (FINAL WORKING ANSWER)**

What AlexMA helped me with was 99% of the way there, it was missing a return statement inside of the axios then, as well as a throw in the catch to throw it an error. Here is the final code. I gave him the check for getting me most of the way there. I had to write out the full URL as I was getting this weird error where that baseUrl variable was adding a path on it inside the axios get that it otherwise was not adding when I did a console log outside of that call. Minor issue, but otherwise this works.

```
 data() {
            this.fakeAxiosCall()
                .then((theData) => (
                    this.data = theData
                ))
                .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
            return {
                data: "",
                loading: true,
                baseUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fakeAxiosCall: function() {
                 return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/mockdata/piemock.json')
                    .then(result => { console.log(result); return result; })
                    .catch(error => { console.error(error); throw error; });
            }
        },
```

Comment: The axios call is asynchronous so its promise won't have resolved yet at the point the `mounted` hook is called. You should be able to see that from the order of the logging.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Is there a way I can do this so I can get that JSON file loaded?

Comment: If it has to be loaded before this component is mounted then you'll need to load it externally and only create the component once the data is available. If you want to keep the loading inside this component then you'll need to handle the data not being available during the initial render.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I will have to research how to pass entire JSON trees of data to a component so that I can create my JSON before the component is created.

Comment: Are you sure you need to avoid having the component created v.s. just hiding the `template` of the component until the data is loaded?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy how would I go about doing that?

Comment: initialize dataset as null instead empty string and add v-if="dataset" in your tag (template, span, or whatelse). Any other option is to use Vue.$nextTick or this.$nextTick when your axios request is resolved but i do not recommend (you can have a beautiful white screen without render because axios failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share some sample code that might be helpful, since it looks like you're trying to do DOM manipulation based on when the data is ready. Hopefully it's helpful. This is a bit of an example of the comment "Are you sure you need to avoid having the component created v.s. just hiding the template of the component until the data is loaded?"

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    this.fakeAxiosCall()
      .then((theData) => (this.data = theData))
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    return {
      data: "",
      loading: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fakeAxiosCall: function() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
         setTimeout(() => resolve("hello Vue"), 2000);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
  <div v-if="!loading">Data was loaded: "{{data}}"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does that fakeAxiosCall const also exist in the component? (And yes I am trying to create a D3JS pie chart component)

Comment: It can exist anywhere, I just made it a const outside of the component as an example. You could move it inside of the `methods` block and call `this.fakeAxiosCall()` if that had a better feel. In a big app it should probably reside in the model layer somewhere, maybe a plain javascript file, vuex, or some other model-layer library. Depends on how you like to structure your app though.

Comment: Ok I made some adjustments to the code but am getting a different issue now, see OP

Comment: In your app it will probably be something like `fakeAxiosCall: function() { return axios.get(this.baseUrl + '/mockdata/piemock.json') }`. But then it doesn't need to be called `fake` of course 

Comment: I updated my answer. The created lifecycle hook is not really necessary in your case.

Comment: See the updated original post. The call to the fakeAxios method is not being called?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. SO is not intended for extended debugging help sessions, so please open a new question if you find a specific bug in your program that you cannot solve.

Comment: ...see update to the OP, you were not that far off.